# Uniqueness of the $J$ invariant

Tags: reference-request, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, sequences-and-series, modular-forms, j-invariant

It seems that

> The $J$ invariant is the unique modular function of weight zero for $\operatorname{SL}(2,\mathbb{Z})$ which is holomorphic away from a simple pole at the cusp such that
> $$J(e^{2\pi i/3})=0,\, J(i)=1.$$

Is the above statement true? If so, can you refer me to a book where this is proved?

To make sure we're on the same page:
$$J(\tau)=\frac{E_4(\tau)^3}{E_4(\tau)^3-E_6(\tau)^2}$$
where $E_4$ and $E_6$ are the normalized Eisenstein series,
$$E_4(\tau)=1+240\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^3 e^{2\pi i\tau n}}{1-e^{2\pi i\tau n}},$$
$$E_6(\tau)=1-504\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^5 e^{2\pi i \tau n}}{1-e^{2\pi i\tau n}}.$$

No one on Math StackExchange knows the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4806812/uniqueness-of-the-j-invariant).

Comment: Isn't $j^2$ another one?

Comment: @DaveBenson No, $j^2$ doesn't have a simple pole at the cusp.

Comment: Another such function, divided by j, would have no poles anywhere, hence be constant, and take the value 1 at one point, hence be 1.

Comment: @WillSawin Is the condition $J(e^{2\pi i/3})=0$ unnecessary?

Comment: @WillSawin How do you show that another such function, divided by j, is bounded? I thought this was necesarry for applying Liouville's theorem.

Comment: A small variant on the strategy @WillSawin proposes: if $f$ is a modular function of weight $0$, holomorphic away from the cusp and with a simple pole at the cusp, then there is some complex number $a$ such that $f-aj$ is holomorphic at the cusp (cancel out the leading term of the pole). The same Liouville argument shows that $f-aj$ is constant, i.e. $f=aj+b$. If you want your normalisation conditions $f(e^{2\pi i/3})=0$ and $f(i)=1$, then this forces $a=1$ and $b=0$, so $f=j$.

Comment: if $f$ is a modular function of weight $0$, holomorphic away from the cusp and with a simple pole at the cusp, then $g=f/J$ has no zeros and poles and must be constant. But $g(i)=1.$

Comment: Serre, *Cours d'arithmétique*, chapter VII, §3, proposition 6(iii), proves that any modular function of weight 0 is a rational function of $j$. Translating your conditions on the rational function in question, it has a simple pole at infinity and none elsewhere, and the conditions at $0$ and $1$ imply that it is the identity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any meromorphic modular function of weight $0$ for $\mathrm{SL}(2,\Bbb Z)$ is a rational function of $j$, say $P(j)$. Since your function is holomorphic, $P$ is a polynomial. Since your function has a simple pole at infinity, $P$ has degree one. But $P$ fixes $0$ and $1$, so it is the identity.